# C - Unexpected Segmentation Fault on strtok(...)

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, token, strtok

I am using strtok(...) of the  library and it appears to be working fine until the end condition, where it results in a segmentation fault and program crash.  The API claims that strtok(...) will output a NULL when there are no more tokens to be found, which meant, I thought, that you had to catch this NULL in order to terminate any loops that you were running using strtok(...).  What do I need to do to catch this NULL to prevent my program from crashing?  I imagined the NULL was allowed for use as a terminating condition.

I have prepared a SSCCE for you to observe this behavior.  I need strtok(...) to work for a much larger piece of software I am writing, and I am getting the exact same segmentation behavior.  The output at the command line is shown below this code vignette (yes I know you use <...> to enclose libraries, but I was having difficulty getting this post to display the code libraries).  I am using gcc version 4.5.3, on a Windows 8 OS, and below shows two different flavors of how I imagine one could try to catch the NULL in a loop.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
  char* from = "12.34.56.78";
  char * ch = ".";
  char * token = strtok(from, ch);
  printf("%s\n",token);
  while(token != NULL){
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
    printf("%s\n", token);
  }
  printf("Broke out of loop!");
  while(strcmp(token, 0) != 0){
    printf("%s\n",token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
  }
}
```

```
############ OUTPUT: ############

$ ./test
12
34
56
78
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: It's never really unexpected when `strtok` segfaults.  It should only be used in conjunction with `gets`  (which is to say, never!)

Comment: `strcmp(NULL,0)` <- boom!

Comment: Aniket may be right but I never make it to the second loop (I edited the above vignette to reflect this--the output is still the same).  @WilliamPursell would you standardly use it with gets(...)?  Are you saying that we can never use strtok b/c it's a broken method?  What is it even good for?  I really like its tokenizing ability, otherwise, my code that was written around it will ballloon ten-fold

Comment: @9codeMan9 My comment was somewhat facetious.  One should absolutely never use `gets`.  `strtok` is not quite as bad, but I typically find that it is not necessary as tokenization is best done via lex/bison/yacc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are first checking if `token` is not equal to NULL(when it is, it breaks out of the `while` loop). Then you are comparing `token`, which is a `NULL` with a constant NUMBER? here: `strcmp(token, 0)` when `strcmp` expects 2 strings, you provide a number. `strcmp` will try to fetch a string at 0th address(or NULL) giving you a segmentation fault.

```
while(strcmp(token, 0) != 0){
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
    printf("%s\n",token);
  }
```

Also this piece of code should be something like the following:

change

```
  char * token = strtok(from, ch);
  printf("%s\n",token);
  while(token != NULL){
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
    printf("%s\n", token);
  }
```

to

```
  char * token = strtok(from, ch);
  printf("%s\n",token);
  while(token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
  }
```

Comment: You were right Aniket, it was the order of the print statements, since I was trying to print a NULL in the first loop by the end.

How would you propose setting up the second loop?  Or was I just misusing strcmp(...) in that portion of the code?

Answer (score 4):

`strtok` modifies its first argument.  You are passing it a string from read-only memory, and the segfault occurs when `strtok` tries to change it.  Try changing from:

```
char* from = "12.34.56.78";
```

to

```
char from[] = "12.34.56.78";
```

Comment: worse yet, he is trying to `strcmp` two NULL values.

Comment: I just tried your solution, I get the exact same output.  I modified the above vignette to show that i never even make it to the second loop.  The output is still the same, complete with segmentation fault...

Comment: ...However, once I changed the print statement order, as per @Aniket and Michael Burr's suggestions, I got it to work.  Interestingly enough, your array solution ''char from[]'' and my original approach''"char * from'' both work.

Comment: 9codeMan9  Be careful using `char *`.   It will work on some platforms, but fail on others.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem:

```
  while(token != NULL){
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
    printf("%s\n", token);
  }
```

You're checking for NULL, but then calling `strtok` again and not checking after that but before printing.

There are other problems with the code, but I suspect this is why it crashes where it does now.

Comment: worse yet, he is trying to `strcmp` two NULL values

Comment: Yes, it turns out the printf(...) needed to be at the start of the loop, by the end I was attempting to print a NULL which created the primary error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that even though you terminate the loop when `strtok()` returns `NULL`, you try to print the `NULL` first:

```
  while(token != NULL){
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
    printf("%s\n", token);    // not good when token is NULL
  }
```

It turns out there are several opportunities in addition to this one for segfaults in this example, as pointed out by other answers.

Here's one way to handle your example tokenization:

```
char from[] = "12.34.56.78";
char * ch = ".";
char * token = strtok(from, ch);
while (token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
}
```

Comment: you were right, changing the order of the printf(...) function worked and allowed the code to make it beyond the first loop.

Answer (score 2):

If purpose of code is only to print element separated by '.',
Only change in char declaration and before printing token check for its value NULL or not !

```
 main(){
        char from[] = "12.34.56.78.100.101";
        char * ch = ".";
        char * token = strtok(from, ch);
        //printf("%s\n",token);
        while(token != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ch);
        }
   }
```

OUTPUT

```
  ./test1
 12
 12
 34
 56
 78
 100
 101
```

Answer (score 1):

You have both memory access errors and logic errors.  I will only address the memory access errors that are causing your program to crash.

`strtok` modifies it's first argument.  Since you are passing in a string literal, it is unable to modify the string (string literals are not modifiable.)

Here's a possible fix to define `from` as a modifiable string array:

```
char from[] = "12.34.56.78";
```

Because `strtok` modifies the string passed into it, you cannot process that string again in your second while loop.  You are essentially passing in a NULL into the `strcmp` function there.  A possible fix would be to copy the `from` array into another buffer each time you wish to use `strtok`.

Comment: What other logic errors did you see besides the strcmp(...) problem?  Or was that the one you noticed?  I do not believe I can do that with strcmp(...), which ultimately boiled down to comparing the 0th memory address (NULL) to NULL.

Comment: As pointed out by a previous poster, this loop prints `token` when it is NULL which is almost surely incorrect:
`while(token != NULL){
    token = strtok(NULL, ch);
    printf("%s\n", token);
  }`